# Excel Chart: X and Y Categories

Tags: excel, charts

In Excel 2010 is it possible to have X and Y categories in a scatter/line graph?

An example would be Simple, Intermediate, Complex on the X axis and Low, Medium, High on the Y axis and three markers in the plot area corresponding to Simple/Low, Intermediate/Medium and Complex/High.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get some numbers in your dataset. A scatter between to categories is in my opinion `can't be plotted and also it doesn't have any utility as such`.

You can have your `categories on one axis (Say X)` and `some values in another axis( Say Y)`, then you can plot the graph.

Your `categories should be unique for scatters`, if a single category comes more than once excel will auto change the categories to number from 1, 2, 3, ....

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bflat.

I was thinking of having hidden axes ranging from 1 to 3 on X and Y and then having the categories overlay them somehow...